# What is this member pointer syntax?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    // ### Member Function ###
    void bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar()\n"; }
};

// ### 1 Parameter Primary Template (which is empty) ###
template<typename>
struct Traits {};

// ### 2 Parameter Template Specialization ###
template<class T, class U>
struct Traits<T U::*>
              ^^^^^^ // I don't understand this syntax
{
    using type1 = T;
    using type2 = U;
};

int main()
{
    // ### Pointer to member function ###
    void (Foo::*memFuncPtr)() = &Foo::bar;
    
    Foo f;

    // ### Use the member function pointer to invoke it ###
    (f.*memFuncPtr)();
    
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(), Traits<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type1>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo, Traits<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type2>);

    return 0;
}
```

How does the specialization syntax work? It makes sense that the `U` in `U::*` is the same as the `Foo` type but why is `T` the same as the `void()` type?

## Edit

After the very useful comments from @user17732522 and answer by @AnoopRana I was able to change the `main` function implementation to use the same syntax (just to see it work).

```
int main()
{
    using F = void();

    // ### Pointer to member function ###
    F Foo::*memFuncPtr = &Foo::bar;

    Foo f;

    // ### Use the member function pointer to invoke it ###
    (f.*memFuncPtr)();

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void(), Traits<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type1>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo, Traits<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type2>);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `Foo::bar` has type `void()`?

Comment: @user17732522 If I expand `T U::*` with the types `void()` and `Foo` it yields `void() Foo::*` which doesn't make any sense can you please elaborate how the `T U::*` syntax is valid?

Comment: @Elliott The return type of the `Foo::bar` function is `void` but `T` **is not `void`** `T` is actually `void()`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Type aliases can generally not be simply replaced as text. That is the same for usual function pointers, e.g. given `using T = void();`, the type `T*` is a pointer-to-`void()`-function, although the syntax for that without alias would be `void(*)()`. The additional modifiers need to be applied semantically to the aliased type.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not familiar with type aliases. Do you have any good links that might provide more details?

Comment: I leave my comment as a godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Prbca5PYK

Although @user17732522 probably has answered it (once I understand what they've said!)

Comment: @JamesAdkison, type aliases are literally just `using T = int`, or (identically) `typedef int T`.

Comment: It's just that `T U::*` means "pointer to member of class U with type T" and here `T` is `void()`. That the declaration syntax without `T` would be `void (U::*)()` doesn't matter.

Comment: @user17732522, oh. So `void()` actually represents the type of a zero-argument function that returns void. I honestly thought it was treating `void` as a value, like `int()` for `int x = int();`

Comment: @Elliott `void()` can be a type of a function without parameters and return type, or it can be an expression of type `void`. Given that we were talking about types, I assumed that it was clear the former interpretation is meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> struct Trait<T U::*>
>              ^^^^^^ // I don't understand this syntax
> ```

The above syntax means that we've a pointer to a member of a class named `U` where the member has type `T`. In other words, a *pointer to a member of class `U` that has type `T`*.

Now let's apply this to `&Foo::bar`. The type of the expression `&Foo::bar` is:

```
void (Foo::* f)()
```

Now you can compare this with `T U::*`

So, after comparing we get:

1. `U = Foo` which is the *class type*.
2. `T = void()` which means a function that has the return type `void` and takes no parameter i.e., a *function type*.

which effectively means that we've a pointer to a member function that has the return type `void` and takes no parameters, of class `Foo`.