# what is the type of member object/function in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the code from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
struct A {
    int fun() const&;
};
 
template<typename>
struct PM_traits {};
 
template<class T, class U>
struct PM_traits<U T::*> {
    using member_type = U;
};
 

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

 
    using T = PM_traits<decltype(&A::fun)>::member_type; // T is int() const&
    std::cout << "#5 " << std::is_function_v<T> << '\n';
}
```

What I know is that the &A::fun stands for the member function pointer of the fun() in class A. So the result of `decltype(&A::fun)` should be `int A::*() const&`.

When it comes to PM_traits, I think the template deduces `U` as `int` and `T` as `A`, but the result of `member_type` in `PM_traits` is not `int`.

I do want to know what is the meaning of `<U T::*>` in the template and how is the type-deducing going on.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help!

Comment: result of `decltype(&A::fun)` should be `int A::*() const&`, as `fun` was declared so

Comment: I doubt think that pointed double answers the problem in THIS question. Here we have issue not with a pointer but with a function type.

Comment: `U` is a function type. As it was deduced from member function with cv-qualifiers, it's qualified one. Function type is an old concept which existed even in C. If you declare function type as a named type, i.e. `using fun_type = int() const&; `, then `struct A { fun_type fun; };` for fun to be a member function.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie This is clearly explained the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805241/what-is-this-member-pointer-syntax) i linked. The only difference is that, here `U` is `int() const&` and there `T` is `void()`. Both of these question are very much the same in all other respects.

Comment: @irasin As explained in the dupe, if you compare `U T::*` with `int A::*() const&` then `T` is deduced to `A` and `U` is deduced to the remaining function type `int() const&` as expected. It's just simple comparison between the passed argument `int A::*() const&` and the `U T::*`. The same is explained there in my answer.

Comment: @irasin Moreover, your assumption that *"template deduces `U` as `int`"* is wrong for the reason i explained in my above comment and also in the linked dupe.

Comment: `SomeType T::*` is pointer to member, which might be a pointer to a function or to a variable. For comparison see how the `int` *variable* produces the result you expected: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/93MfqEhvE). @AnoopRana Perhaps nice to better illustrate in your answer *there*, too?